# PDOException Error While saving the view

Tags: views, javascript

I get this Error when i save a view of format JCarousel.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'slidersidebar' for key 2: INSERT INTO {views_view}
>   (name, description, tag, base_table, human_name, core) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => slidersidebar [:db_insert_placeholder_1]
>   => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => default [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => Slider Sidebar
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 7 ) in views_db_object->save_row() (line
>   2092 of
>   /home/kumarang/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc).

Comment: When i save the view for the first time it doesnt save the view or show any error messages. When i click on the save button again i get the above message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run update.php for your site; clear cache as well.

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem

Comment: error shows "Duplicate entry" means u have submit twice. as u also write in your comment. can u paste screenshot?

Comment: I am unable to upload image as i have less repuatation

Comment: reload the view page and see if there is any message like "Break the lock". upload your image at tinypic.com/ and paste link in post

Comment: There is no lock on the view. Here's the URL http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=zkom6d&s=6

Comment: can u not create a new view? image shown only error, hoping for full page image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8057/discussion-between-prem-anand-and-monymirza)